# SQL server created linked server using catalog option

Tags: sql, sql-server, linked-server

I am trying to create a new linked server.

I am using provider as SQL Server Native Client 11.0

I have entered Product Name and Data Source

If I create connection using these settings it works just fine.

But I am trying to create a linked server using catalog option where I enter the Db name example AdventureWorks

Now when I create connection, and expand new connection I just created

Then further Expand Catalogs folder

I see more than one databases, where as it should only show the one I specified while creating the linked server connection in the catalog option.

Can any tell me why this is happening? I have not been able to find anything related to this. Please let me know if you have any further questions.

Comment: Linked Servers are not inherently limited to a single database, that's just the *default* database you are entering.  If you really want to restrict it to a single database, then you'll need to setup the security controls for that.

Answer (score 1):

I've found that the provider `SQL Server Native Client 11.0` does do this and allows access to all catalogs. If you don't want this it sounds like you want to use the `Microsoft OLE DB Provider for SQL Server` as this allows you to specify a catelog (default database) and it only show you and allow access to that one database